# org.w3c.dom.Element get position in parent

Tags: java, xml

How to get the position of an Element in the childNode list?

e.g.

```
<a>
  <b></b><!-- return 0 -->
  <c></c><!-- return 1 -->
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think [`Element`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html), [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), or [`NodeList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) provide a direct way to get this info, but it's easy enough to write your own quick function to do it:

```
int indexOfNode(Node node) {
    int index;
    Node sibling;

    index = 0;
    while ((sibling = node.getPreviousSibling()) != null) {
        node = sibling;
        ++index;
    }

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straightforward way other than to repeatedly call `getPreviousSibling()` until it returns null or iterate through the parent node's child list until you find one that is `==` to the node you started with.

As an aside, in the document you give in the question the `b` element is index 1 in its parent's list of children, and the `c` element is index 3, because there are whitespace-only text nodes in between (one between the opening `a` and opening `b` and another between the closing `b` and opening `c`).